# iOS Mobile Browser scrolling issue with position:fixed, Page jumps back to top when scroll ends

Tags: ios, css, ipad, scroll, shopify

I found a number of issues with the `POSITION:FIXED` property on iOS Mobile. But it didnt resolved my issue. In desktops and in Android devices, works perfectly. Even in MacBook Air also.

ISSUE:

I have a `position:fixed` header, and a `position:relative` content (using `padding-top:height-of-header` for alignment). When i scroll **fast**, it starts scroll and then suddenly, it jumps back to the top of the page. But this issue is not showing when we scroll **slowly**.

This is the code for **header**

```
.site-header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

this is the code for **main-content**

```
  .main-content {
    padding-top: 80px;
    position:relative;
  }
```

Tried with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` , `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);`.

Its an e-commerce website, developed in **SHOPIFY**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was, in shopify, there were some third party **applications** (that's how they used to call plugins) are used. so, somehow jQuery plugins got conflicts and once i remove the plugin, issue got resolved. i don't know how jQuery effects my css code. but it got resolved when i remove/update the library.